# Aumentar de 2 em 2 quando ativar a function

Tags: javascript, funções

Olá, sou iniciante em javascript e gostaria de saber como faço para bloquear o item, quando var total atingir tal valor igual ao do item, ex: 200,  aumentar de 2 em 2 não de 1 em 1.

```js
var total = 1;
function clickAumento () {
  document.getElementById('marioClick').value = total++;

}
```

```html
<div id="divContador">
    <input type="text" id="marioClick" value="0"></input>
</div>
<div id="divMario"> 
   <img onclick="clickAumento()" id="mario" src="http://www.imagenspng.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/super-mario-mario-11.png">
</div>
```

Comment: tentou usar `total+2`?

Comment: **João** sua pergunta esta confusa, não da pra entender. Pois diz: **como faço para bloquear o item, quando desbloquear no click**, poderia [**editar**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/299283/edit) e esclarecer melhor seu problema ou dificuldade ?

Comment: O que quer dizer com "bloquear"?

Comment: Editei!! basicamente fundamentos de um jogo clicker

Comment: bloquear o click?

Answer (score 3):

Em relação ao que diz respeito ao incremento de +2 sugiro:

```
function clickAumento () {
  document.getElementById('marioClick').value = total += 2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Há muitas formas de fazer isso. Uma delas é usando o método `removeAttribute` para remover o `onclick` quando atingir o número desejado.

No tocante à incrementação de 2 em 2, troque o `total++` por `total+=2`.

No exemplo abaixo, quando o número atingir 20 (só para exemplo), o atributo `onclick` é removido e não haverá mais ação quando a imagem for clicada:

```js
var total = 1;
function clickAumento () {
//   if(total < 200){
   if(total < 20){
  document.getElementById('marioClick').value = total+=2;
   }else{
      document.getElementById("mario").removeAttribute("onclick");
   }

}
```

```html
<div id="divContador">
    <input type="text" id="marioClick" value="0"></input>
</div>
<div id="divMario"> 
   <img height="300" onclick="clickAumento()" id="mario" src="http://www.imagenspng.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/super-mario-mario-11.png">
</div>
```